# preg_match multiple results for one string

Tags: php, preg-match

I have the following line:

```
[0;50]
```

I have the following preg_match

```
preg_match('/([0-9]+)/',$price,$ranges);
```

I want to extract the 0 and the 50 in an array like this

```
Array(
    [0] => 0,
    [1] => 50
)
```

How can i do this?

Comment: `preg_match_all('/[0-9]+/',$price,$ranges); print_r($ranges[0]);`

Comment: $price="[0,50]";
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+/',$price,$ranges);
print_r($ranges[0]);